# Better way to update MongoDB subdocuments

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to update particular subdocuments(multiple), For which I have two methods. I want to know which one is better to follow.

**Sample Document**

```
{ 
  _id: 1,
  doc: [{
       prop1: false,
       prop2: 1
  },{
       prop1: false,
       prop2: 1
  },{
       prop1: true,
       prop2: 2
  }]
}
```

**Method1:**

```
db.docs.findOne({}, function(err, result){
    if(err || !result) return next(err || []);
    result.doc.forEach(function(doc){
      if(doc.prop2 === 1){
        doc.prop1 = true;
      }
    });
    doc.save();
});
```

**Method2:**

```
db.docs.findOne({_id: 1}, function(err, result){
    if(err || !result) return next(err || []);
    var bulk = db.docs.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    result.doc.forEach(function(doc){
      if(doc.prop2 === 1){
         bulk.find({
            _id: 1,
            "doc.prop2": 1
            }).update({
                $set: {
                   "doc.$.prop1": true
                }
            });
      }
    });
    bulk.execute();
});
```

Please suggest. let me know if any query.

Comment: Use $unwind(https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) which deconstructs an array field from the input documents to output a document for each element. Each output document is the input document with the value of the array field replaced by the element.

Comment: @Blastfreak $unwind is operator of aggregate cycle. Here I am trying to update multiple subdocuments, Not to find them in a plain format. So just want to know which one is a better method to update multiple subdocuments. How deconstructs would help me to update multiple subdocuments?

Answer (score 1):

With the Bulk API in Mongo shell and the Node.js driver, as each operation is added, if it is of the same type as the previous operation, it gets added to a batch of operations of that type. Otherwise, it is used to create a new batch. When execute() is called, these batches are run in the order they were created.

With the Bulk API we got an estimated 4000 operations per second (and with 100,000 records being updated, around 5000 operations per second). It's quite a boost for doing large numbers of operations, as long as the class of operation is the same.

As per your code the pattern of find/update/find/update... as this will nullify all the performance gains. A rule of thumb is to use the Bulk API's more attractive semantics to only execute same class operations. That way, you will be assured of good performance.

So I suggest to use method1 for your operation.